# meaning of 'was to be the date'

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage, to-infinitive

> It was provisionally agreed that August 12 was to be the date.

What's the meaning of 'was to be the date' here?

Does this mean 'the date should (has to) be August 12' or simply 'August 12 is scheduled (expected) to be the date'?

Comment: Not 'has to be', but simply that it was the date agreed upon.

Comment: Need more context. Has the date since changed?

Answer (score 1):

It means that August 12 was the date chosen or scheduled. It wouldn't normally mean that it HAD to be that date. Though I suppose it could mean that if the context indicated.

"Was" is past tense so this implies that August 12 is no longer the selected date. But in context it could mean that the agreement on the date happened in the past, but the selected date is still in force.

Note that we use similar wording for things besides dates.

We agreed that Fred Miller was the best man for the job.

It was decided that Boston was to be the place for the convention.

Etc.